# LWC: Show Toast from Service component

Tags: lightning-web-components, toast

I need to show toast from LWC service component, but I don't have and won't have any instance of LWC component.
That means no class which extends LightningElement.

This service will be used in Aura components. I just want to utilize ES6 features in the service.

How can I display toast in LWC without having LightningElement?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I've thought of so far, is to wrap promise error in separate Error object with showToast(A) method and then in aura components do:

```
        TheAPIService.searchExternalCustomers({creditCardNumber: '4111111111111111'})
            .catch(error => error.showToast($A));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about whats going on in your ES6, you could have a callback function that you can pass from aura.

Answer (score 0):

If LWC is a service, I don't suppose it should show any toast at all - it should remain framework agnostic. 
Why not dispatching an event from LWC that the aura component would listen to and display the toast in aura?

Comment: It's not framework agnostic. It's a service which provides interface for external callouts through apex in Aura and LWC. It will never possibly be framework agnotstic :)


The goal is that it provides the default error handling (the toast), because that will be 99.9% of the cases, with possibility to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't use LightningElement because I couldn't find the methods on it.
Turns out I was only missing @api annotation and that's it.

Still, Aura initializes before LWC so all my methods are completely useless in aura's "init" phase.